# How to pass a class name to a XML Parsing Function in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xml-parsing

I dont know why I am stuck at this but need some help here. I have multiple classes with multiple properties. I am trying to parse an XML file using this method mentioned below.

```
private  void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string XMLFilePath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "UTC34.xml");
            //string data = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

            if(File.Exists(XMLFilePath))
            {

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(XMLFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                TextReader ff = new StreamReader(fs);
                XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(ff.ReadToEnd());
                XmlSerializer ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightPlan));
                using (var reader = xmldoc.CreateReader())
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightPlan));
                    FlightPlan someTest = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as FlightPlan;
                    // NotSupportedException here (as inner exception)
                }


            }
```

I am stuck up here

> XmlSerializer ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightPlan));//FlightPlan is a class

I want to write a method wherein I pas they Classname as there are multiple classes in the XML file.I dont want to write multiple functions for multiple classes .

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well this is going to happen in response to a button click - how do you know which class to use at that point?

Comment: @JonSkeet jon I am working on a POC. I have a big XML file for which I genereated C# classes, one XML file has multiple classes and the data never changes. I was just thinking that only one function can be called and it serializes all the XML data into those classes . how can I do that?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It would be much better if you'd provide a [mcve] - with two classes (just with a single property each) and some representative XML, then a console application that produced the XML and what you've tried to parse it.

Comment: @JonSkeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413065/how-to-make-an-xml-serializable

Comment: @JonSkeet can you help me ?

Comment: No, as you still haven't written a clear question IMO. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code snippet I use for xml serialization.

```
public static class Serializer<T> where T : class
{
    public static void Serialize(string filename, T obj)
    {
        using (TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(filename, false))
        {
            XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, obj);
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs))
                {
                    if (SerializerObj.CanDeserialize(reader))
                    {
                        return SerializerObj.Deserialize(reader) as T;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update**

To pass in multiple classes, you should create another class that contains the others.

```
[Serializable]
class Container
{
    public MyClass1 One { get; set; }
    public MyClass2 Two { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
class MyClass1
{

}

[Serializable]
class MyClass2
{

}
```

Then call

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Serializer<Container>.Serialize("path", new Container());
    }
```

Comment: how do I pass multiple class names? I have a big XML file that I converted to C# classes. the converted C# class file has 50 classes . I need to pass all those 50 names into a single function so that i can serialize. can you help ?

Comment: Serializer works this out on it's own based on the properties of the root object that you are deserializing. You only need to provide it with the root object type just like in example above (replace T with your type)

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell thanks alot. Let me check and get back to you ?

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell If possible can you come on chat?

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell I am unable to add [serializable] attribute to my C# XML classes.  I have Pasted Special the XML file in VS as C# classes. Kindly help.

Comment: show a code example of a class you can't serialize. also, what platform are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 and working on a UWP app

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell I am trying to follow your hints but why I m unable to add [serializable] attribute into my claases ? i used this link to regenerate new classes -http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell [Serializable] attribute is not available for UWP . I have [DataMember] & [Datacontract] .

Comment: You need to install the NuGet package System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters

Answer (score 0):

I use it like this:

```
string classname = typeof(FlightPlan).Name;
```

Or

```
this.GetType().Name
```

pass this as a parameter or call .Name on the type.