# How to make an XML Serializable?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I had an XML File that I needed to serialize. I used VS feature Paste Special->Convert XML to C# Classes feature and got the C# classes for that XML file.

The C# file for the XML has Multiple Classes as shown in the image below:

[image]

The generated C# of XML has the following structure

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://example.com/633")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/633", IsNullable = false) ]

        public partial class FlightPlan
        {

            private FlightPlanM633Header m633HeaderField;

            private FlightPlanM633SupplementaryHeader m633SupplementaryHeaderField;
------
-----
}
```

I want to add the `[serializable]` attribute and go ahead with the serializing the whole XML. I am unable to add `[serializable]` attribute.

Comment: The attribute property cannot go on a class, it need to be before each property in the class and must be on a primitive like int, string, double...

Comment: how do I change my XML ? its all generated by Visual Studio. Need to parse it

Comment: "I had an XML File that I needed to serialize" - an XML file would be the *result* of serialization. Like your other question, this is unclear IMO.

Comment: REmove the XmlTypeAttribute the is posted and move to appropriate location in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Paste Special > Paste Xml As Classes* command already adds the `SerializableAttribute` the classes it creates so no need to add them yourself. You should be able to serialization straight away:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FlightPlan));

            // Deserialize
            FlightPlan o = (FlightPlan)
                serializer.Deserialize(new StreamReader("source.xml"));

            // Serialize
            serializer.Serialize(new StreamWriter("Out.xml"), o);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I have multiple classes in the same XML? The above code is for only 1 class file by the name FlightPlan

Comment: This is difficult to answer without seeing more of the code that's generated or the XML from which you generated the classes. If you set properties on the `FlightPlan` object then they should get serialized as well.

Comment: Let me update the C# code for XML for the next class as well !

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136448/how-to-make-an-xml-serializable

Comment: Are you available ?